# How to display the title according to the ID that is in the API in nextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a problem, I just want to display the "title" according to the ID. but instead all the "titles" appear.
like the picture below
[image]

My Code =

```
const getData = () => {
        const fetchArticle = profile.userId ? getNews : getAllNews;

        fetchArticle({ row: 10, page: 1 })
            .then((resolve) => {
                console.log(resolve);
                setNewsList(resolve.lists.map((news) => ({ ...news, news: news._id })));
            })
            .catch((reject) => {
                console.log(reject);
            });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getData();
    }, []);

return(
{newsList.map((news, _id) => {
                            return (
                                <>
                                    <div key={_id}>
                                    <h2>{news.title}</h2>
                                    <p className={styles.publish}>Published On: {news.createdAt}</p>
                                    <p>{news.content}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </>
                            );
                        })}
)
```

can anyone help me? I'm sorry if the writing structure of my question is messed up, because I'm just learning coding. **Thank you**

Comment: Can you clarify the problem? Is that image the result you expect?

Comment: Problem = I want to display the data "title" according to its id. for example, I open the url abc.com/1 then title id 1 appears. if I open abc.com/2 then title id 2 appears.

The picture above is the problem, I open abc.com/1 which appears instead all the title data. what should appear is the title belonging to id 1

Comment: Did you setup the routes?

Comment: I'd recommend a read through https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `useParams` hook to get article ID from the URL.

So, first you need to create a route for that (you can do that somewhere in your App component):

```js
function App() {
  // some code
  return (
      <Router>
          <Routes>
              <Route path=":articleId" element={<YourComponent />} />
          </Routes>
      </Router>
   );
}
```

Note that `react-router-dom` should be installed and imported:

```js
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Then in your articles component:

```js
const { articleId } = useParams(); // make sure to import useParams from react-router-dom

// some code and your getData function

const currentNews = newsList.filter((news) => news._id == articleId)[0];

return (
    <div key={currentNews._id}>
        <h2>{currentNews.title}</h2>
        <p className={styles.publish}>Published On: {currentNews.createdAt}</p>
        <p>{currentNews.content}</p>
    </div>
);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Next.js has a [built-in file-system based router](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router), it doesn't use `react-router-dom`.